# Better way to write wordle score averager?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, wordle-game

I've got a spreadsheet tracking my partner and I's wordle scores, tracking an average.

```
Win Turns, Me, Them
1, 0, 0
2, 1, 2
3, 4, 9
4, 12, 8
5, 5, 9
6, 2, 6
```

And the formula to calculate the average looks like this:

```
=((C2*A2)+(C3*A3)+(C4*A4)+(C5*A5)+(C6*A6)+(C7*A7))/sum(C2:C7)
```

I'm using Google sheets. Is there a better way to write this??

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is [opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and code reviews are to be asked here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: answer updated...

Answer (score 3):

if you want something short you can use

```
=INDEX(SUM(C2:C*A2:A)/SUM(C2:C))
```

[image]

or:

```
=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(A2:A, C2:C)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much player0. Is there a way to specify MOST of the column and to keep the average at the bottom of the scores in the spreadsheet? I gather the :C  and :A in your ranges means "the whole column", and I'm wondering if there's a way to specify a limit.

Comment: @Locane unlimited ranges like C2:C can be ofc changes to limited ones like C2:C7